# List of Subject Dependencies for building a subject taxonomy

Tags: mathematics, computer-science, education, learning

I am interested in compiling a list of learning dependencies by subject matter. E.g., you must know certain kinds of algebra before you can learn certain aspects of trig, and you must know how to add before you can do certain kinds of algebra.

This kind of hierarchy could be applied to math, computer science, biology, written/spoken languages, etc.

Is there a project like this already established? Is there a field of study that concentrates on an idea similar to this?

Comment: As others are implying, learning does not work that way.  It is not actually systematic.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I'm not asking about learning, I'm asking about subjects themselves.

Answer (score 3):

I think that prerequisites do not apply to topics and subjects, but to lectures and books. For example, I can tell you what you have to know to follow my course on calculus, but it is quite difficult to say what you have to know before you can understand a derivative. You can either take the real numbers for granted, or give a fake-definition via Cauchy-sequences or Dedikind cuts, or give a real definition within the framework of a fixed set theory. Bourbakists would choose the latter, while all courses I know, which are actually aimed at first year students, pick one of the first two options.

Another problem is that prerequisites are subject to substitutions. If subject A is considered important, and subject B is not part of the mainstream, a lecture on A will rather make detours than using B, while a lecture on B will freely use everything from subject A. For example, the fundamental theorem of algebra is most often proven by complex analytic or topological, and not by real analytic or algebraic means. The reason is simply that most people learn complex analysis before they learn Galois theory, and the real analytic proof is more computational, i.e. not "nice".

Comment: Prerequisites for classes and books do not exist _per se_, as they are the logical **result** of the discipline-focused or interdisciplinary _topical (subject) learning hierarchies of dependencies_. (I am talking about core concepts; obviously, some deviations are possible.)

Comment: If you can reach the same goal by many different routes, the prerequisites depend on the route, not on the goal. The way we teach students depends a lot on tradition and perceived importance of subjects, may be more than on the logical dependence of the subjects.

Comment: Fair enough! I was just expressing my opinion. I'm sure you know these things better, Professor :-).

Answer (score 0):

While the term "learning hierarchies" is used quite often, I think that either *learning dependencies* or *learning prerequisites* would be a more accurate term (the latter is obviously more often used in the education process context, i.e. see [this page](http://www.ucsd.edu/catalog/courses/MATH.html) and [this page](http://cs.wellesley.edu/~cs/Curriculum/dependencies.html), while the former IMHO carries a more general knowledge acquisition connotation). While I am not aware of any *cross-disciplinary (interdisciplinary)* dependencies in an academic context, from a *general knowledge management* perspective, I would refer to [ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology) and [taxonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomy_%28general%29) as the relevant topics. One of general learning taxonomies (important from pedagogical standpoint) is [Bloom's taxonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom's_taxonomy), however, your question, as I understand it, asks for *domain-aware learning taxonomies*.

Having said that, let's focus on mathematics, for illustrative purposes and due to its general nature. The following are some relevant and/or related math-related (except the last item) resources that you might find useful in the context of your question.

- The [*Further Mathematics Support Programme* prerequisites](http://www.furthermaths.org.uk/prereqs) (see linked documents)
- Classic 1981 paper ["Hierarchies in mathematics education"](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00305622) by Kathleen Hart
- ["An Educational Ontology for Teaching University Courses"](http://www.icvl.eu/2011/disc/icvl/documente/pdf/met/ICVL_ModelsAndMethodologies_paper08.pdf) by Mihaela Oprea (research paper, presenting an interesting ontology-based and discipline-independent approach to learning)

Comment: Thanks for the information! An excellent start to the discussion!

Comment: @anp: My pleasure!